# Can't control drop down list with a mouse

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have two iframes side by side (they are in divs). The target pages didn't fit right into them so i used:

```
#historyGraph, #realtimeGraph
{
zoom: 0.85;
-moz-transform: scale(0.85);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0; 
}
```

Everything looks good however there are problems with drop down lists. I can open it with a mouse. It opens up slightly offset to the right and to the bottom and the only way to make a selection is to use keyboard.

Any way of fixing this?

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBQaf/

[image: Image:]

Comment: That's weird, maybe setting origin to the center of the screen will help? Could you also please post a jsfiddle?

Comment: in all browser or specifically firefox?

Comment: IE shows it good. Here's my ugly code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBQaf/ I am using different website here. Drop down list is on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=759993 for more info.

Comment: I found workaround to this by inserting `select { -moz-transform: scale(1);` in page's stylesheet. However I am transforming iframe and this doesn't work. Any way of applying this fix to my target page in iframe?